# PyCharm + SQLAlchemy , unresolved reference SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pycharm

All code compiles with no issues however PcCharm keeps complaining about SQLAlchemy,what could be the problem here?

Comment: Show your traceback (By the way there is no compilation), If you are sure that `SQLAlchemy` is installed at your interpreter try `File` -> `Invalidate Caches` -> Restart PyCharm.

Comment: Yup,everything works as it should,no error or anything apart from the unresolved underline in IDE :( Invalidate caches also not worked...

Comment: importing flask_sqlalchemy instead of flask.ext.sqlalchemy does it for now :)

Comment: Sometimes PyCharm "cannot find reference" to SQLAlchemy classes because it has stubs in `.PyCharm*/system/python_stubs`. If so, remove/rename `sqlalchemy` directory/directories in _subdirectories_ of `python_stubs`